# Combinar dos TreeMap desde una funcion en Java

Tags: java, funciones

Estoy tratando de hacer una función que reciba como parámetros dos TreeMap y los combine entre ellos. Mi problema está en que no encuentro como pasar como parámetro un TreeMap genérico para que reciba cualquier tipo de TreeMap, es decir, se debe específicar el tipo de dato de la Key y el Valor, pero la idea de la función es que me reciba cualquier dato dentro del TreeMap sin importar cuál sea.

```
public void compararTree(TreeMap<String, Integer>map1, TreeMap<String, Integer>map2) {
    TreeMap<String, Integer> combinado = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> ent : map2.entrySet()) {
        combinado.put(ent.getKey(), ent.getValue());
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> ent : map1.entrySet()) {
        combinado.put(ent.getKey(), ent.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println(combinado.keySet() + " - " + combinado.values());
}
```

He intentado con haciendo lo siguiente:

```
public void compararTree(TreeMap map1, TreeMap map2)
```

pero entonces el metodo `map.Entry` me genera error porque sigue esperando el TreeMap con los dos parámetros para la Key y el Value.

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que buscas, simplemente haz tu método genérico. Quedaría:

```
public <K, V> void combinarTree(TreeMap<K, V> map1, TreeMap<K, V> map2) {
        TreeMap<K, V> combinado = new TreeMap<>();
        combinado.putAll(map1);
        combinado.putAll(map2);

        System.out.println(combinado.keySet() + " - " + combinado.values());
    }
```